# Get List received emails shown in Google Admin Gmail Reports

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-workspace

I have tried to use the using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 in C# to find the list of emails received by a user in my G suite domain.  I need to get, for a specific email, the number of all received emails in a range of dates.

I need to count all received emails and get a result like that in Google Admin Gmail Reports.  I can find the count of all received emails.: admin.google.com/AdminHome#Reports:subtab=email-log-search

Is it possible to call an API and get reports data?

Which is the query that I've to do?

Is it possible with this API?

Comment: Aren't "deleted" emails deleted? As in, no longer stored anywhere?

Comment: @rene yes deleted is deleted but trashed would still show.  Depends on OP's definition of deleted.

Comment: @badozvora i have edited your question to reflect that this is more a gsuite question then a gmail question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Q paramater in the [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) method to search for anything that you can search for in Gmail.  Testing the search in the Gmail web application is the easest way.

```
var request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
request.Q = "to:(xxx@gmail.com) after:2019/12/1 before:20119/12/31"
var results = request.Execute();
```

This should return any email by this user for those dates.  Even if its in spam or trash.   Deleted emails are actually deleted so your not going to see those.

Comment: Hi DalmTo,
I already used a similar query to get emails in a range of date but deleted email are excluded. I need to count all received emails and get a result like that in Google Admin Gmail Reports...here I can find the count of all received emails.: https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#Reports:subtab=email-log-search Is it possible to call an API and get reports data?

Comment: Deleted is deleted if you cant see it in Gmail it doesnt exist in the gmail API.   Have you tried digging around in https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference to see if you can find the information that report was created with.